# Logout Redirect Uri für Action on Google?

Tags: identityserver4, actions-on-google

I´m developing a action for Google, I´m using Visual Studio C' with Identity Server 4. I followed the instructions from Gooogle to create my client but now I have a question, I´ve been testing my action for a while with my client and it works very well.

```
 new Client
            {
               ClientId = ApiDefinitions.ClientIdGoogle,
               RedirectUris = {  "https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/projectId"},
               PostLogoutRedirectUris = {},
...(cut for readable code)
```

I was wondering if I am missing something in PostLogoutRedirectUris.. Does anyone knows what to give there?

Comment: Or is PostLogoutRedirectUri something irrelevant for an action? Because youre always logged in with your google account.. and when you exit the action and try to reuse it, it will load a login webpage (if the token expired)??

Comment: For AoG there isn't a logout URI, but people are able to revoke the token in the Assistant settings.

Comment: Thank u :@NickFelker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Actions on Google there isn't a logout URI as part of the OAuth flow. People are able to revoke the account linking and your auth token in the Assistant settings.